# How to extract stuck dummy SD card

Tags: sd-card

This is going to sound stupid, but I put in the dummy SD card in the wrong way and now it's stuck. How do I get it out without disassembling the PC? I have a Lenovo Y510p.

Comment: I would probably try a small pair of [pliers](http://www.scalemodelguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Pliers1.jpg).

Comment: I fixed it with a paperclip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to take it out using Multi-function Paper Cutter with Push-lock Blade System. But I guess anything flat and sharp, can be inserted in the upper and low thin gap and pull out using the blade.